# Cordova 2.2 Android the JAR of this class file belongs to container android dependencies

Tags: java, android, cordova

Im having an issue with an app im building. Im trying to add a calendar event in a cordova plugin, but the following isnt working.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, calendarStart.toString());
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, calendarEnd.toString());
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "test event");
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Test event!");
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
                     this.cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

the call to insert gives me a problem with the jar "which does not allow modifications to source attachments on its entries"

Does anybody have any idea how to solve this?